# Get set of unique values from a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries.I want to generate a set of the values of the respective nested lists so that I end up with a set of all of the unique items (in this case, "date" and "sicil").

```
a=[{'id': 709560, 'date': '27.11.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0},
     {'id': 709561, 'date': '27.11.2019', 'sicil': '3430', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0},
     {'id': 709562, 'date': '27.11.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0}, 
     {'id': 709563, 'date': '28.11.2019', 'sicil': '3430', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 385, 'normalizeCycleTime': 0.998271392},
     {'id': 709568, 'date': '28.11.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0},
     {'id': 709569, 'date': '02.12.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0}, 
     {'id': 709570, 'date': '02.12.2019', 'sicil': '3430', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0},
     {'id': 709571, 'date': '02.12.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0},
     {'id': 709575, 'date': '03.12.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 385, 'normalizeCycleTime': 0.998271392},
     {'id': 709576, 'date': '03.12.2019', 'sicil': '3430', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 355, 'normalizeCycleTime': 0.997191011},
     {'id': 709577, 'date': '03.12.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 385, 'normalizeCycleTime': 0.998271392}, 
     {'id': 709585, 'date': '04.12.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0},
     {'id': 709586, 'date': '04.12.2019', 'sicil': '3430', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0}]
```

I want to create for dates:

```
unique_dates={'27.11.2019', '28.11.2019', '02.12.2019', '03.12.2019', '04.12.2019'}
```

Comment: Please post your expected output along with what you have tried

Comment: try pandas `import pandas as pd; pd.DataFrame(a).drop_duplicates(subset=['date', 'sicil'])`

Comment: I don't see any nested lists here.

Comment: Please share expected output and correct you question because its not explanatory enough.

Comment: So you want  `set(d['date'] for d in a)`?

Comment: Yes, thanks @Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below ,

```
a=[{'id': 709560, 'date': '27.11.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0},
     {'id': 709561, 'date': '27.11.2019', 'sicil': '3430', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0},
     {'id': 709562, 'date': '27.11.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0}, 
     {'id': 709563, 'date': '28.11.2019', 'sicil': '3430', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 385, 'normalizeCycleTime': 0.998271392},
     {'id': 709568, 'date': '28.11.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0},
     {'id': 709569, 'date': '02.12.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0}, 
     {'id': 709570, 'date': '02.12.2019', 'sicil': '3430', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0},
     {'id': 709571, 'date': '02.12.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0},
     {'id': 709575, 'date': '03.12.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 385, 'normalizeCycleTime': 0.998271392},
     {'id': 709576, 'date': '03.12.2019', 'sicil': '3430', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 355, 'normalizeCycleTime': 0.997191011},
     {'id': 709577, 'date': '03.12.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 385, 'normalizeCycleTime': 0.998271392}, 
     {'id': 709585, 'date': '04.12.2019', 'sicil': '3119', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0},
     {'id': 709586, 'date': '04.12.2019', 'sicil': '3430', 'uretimSuresiMakina': 445, 'normalizeCycleTime': 1.0}]

set(d['date'] for d in a)
```

output

```
{'02.12.2019', '03.12.2019', '04.12.2019', '27.11.2019', '28.11.2019'}
```

Answer (score 0):

`{dict['date'] for dict in a}`

this will create a set (which is a unique list of values) from a set comprehension emitting the value of the key: 'date'